# Laravel 5.2: Is it possible to use where clause condition in eloquent object

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Fetched the initial data by joining the other table

```
$results = Model::join('joining other table')
                ->where('initial condition')
                ->limit(100)->get();
```

Now, i need to filter the data by some additional condition.

```
$new = $results->where('column',value); // Additional Condition
```

I had tried this but it returns empty collection, even though persist in the $results collection. Is it possible to use the where condition in later part ?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use model relationships, which is very powerful. If you define your relationships between the different models you can call:

```
User::with(['posts' => function($builder){
  $builder->where('published', true) // this is on the relationship (posts)
}])->get();
```

You can also do the following:

```
Post::whereHas(['user' => function($builder){
    $builder->where('confirmed', true);
}])->get();
```

That will only return the posts where the associated user is confirmed...

Comment: Thanks. Yes i agree, this can be done in relationships or whereHas methods. But i want to know, whether this can be done in where method of collection object, as mentioned here in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-where)

Comment: I don't actually know. Maybe you can use the dot notation like where ('user.confirmed', true)... I haven't tried, but maybe it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`Model::join('joining other table')
->where('initial condition')
->where('column',value)
->limit(100)->get();`

Comment: yes this can be achieved in multiple where clause methods. i want to know, whether this can be done in where method of collection object, as mentioned here in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-where)

Comment: Sorry I've never used the collections for the moment. I assume that it would work as the same. If not I would recomend u to visit https://laracasts.com/discuss you might get better feedback. :)